# How to get rows from db from eg fifth row to tenth?

Tags: django

How to get rows from db from selected row interval? For example:
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.

how to tell django to return rows from 3 to 6?

Comment: you shouldn't do this. Rows are unordered, you shouldn't rely on their order but on their content.

Comment: this kind of request already exist on stackoverflow, check on it you will find couple of helpful answers.

Comment: Are you looking for [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/pagination/)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use slice syntax similar what you use on lists:

```
YourModel.objects.order_by('column_name')[2:6]
```

Comment: This solution with `order_by` is much better because the selection should be usually reproducible, e.g. if you want to get the same results after page refresh or after click Next + Previous and not to get a random sample of any three items.

Answer (score 2):

Querysets accept the list slice syntax which is translated into LIMIT/OFFSET.

```
MyModel.objects.all()[3:6]
```